# Installer NVMe Support (Dell XPS 15 9560)

Tags: release-loki, system-installation, drivers, hardware, ssd

In attempting to install Elementary OS on my XPS 15 9560 (i7, 32GB ram, 1TB ssd), I've run into the issue with the installer not recognizing my main (and only) SSD drive. On the 9560 it happens to be NVMe.

The laptop came pre-configured to use "RAID" (so Windows can use Intel's RST) and from what I understand, setting it to AHCI will cause it to be recognized by linux. However, doing so will cause issues with the pre-installed Windows 10 (that I do not want to/cannot remove because I need it for Visual Studio).

Is there any way to get Intel RST/Raid/NVMe drivers for the installer so that I can install without changing the bios setting to AHCI?

Answer (score 0):

Try [this guide](https://github.com/rcasero/doc/wiki/Ubuntu-linux-on-Dell-XPS-15-(9560)) for installing Ubuntu on XPS 9560. It worked for mine Elementary OS on XPS 9560 (512 GB SSD version).

Comment: Yeah I found that guide as well, but I was trying to avoid having to do the Raid->AHCI change (which I know will work around my issue). Since Windows is still going to be the primary OS, I was hoping to preserve the Intel RST stuff, but I'll consider it anyway.